# Authenticating CloudRun with Access Token for Developers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to connect to a service running using Cloud Run (managed). The instance is not public and only in development. Hence I am authenticating using id tokens to authenticate the connection as given in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/developers).

I see that here they use identity token instead of access token to make the request. Why is that ? Also is there a way I could use access token instead ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access tokens are meant for Google’s own APIs (*.googleapis.com).  For example, a Google identity’s (service account, user account) access token allows them to make calls to Google’s API.

However, "identity token" is a proof that you hold that account. These are still tokens, but they’re signed by Google to prove. You can’t use these to make API calls to Google.

Imagine this scenario: Someone has hacked the private service you are calling. But that Cloud Run service has no permissions to do anything. If you sent your access_token, they could intercept and extract that to make API calls with the permission of "caller" service. But if you send your identity_token, it's not usable for anything other than proving "caller" is who it claims it is.

If you have trouble using identity tokens, please feel free to open another question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of Ahmet answer (about the difference between the Identity token and the access token), I would like to add some insight

- You can't, in your code, generate an identity token with your user credential (*at least a Google signed identity token, accepted by Google Front End*)
- Consequently, you need to have a service account key file to generate an identity token in your code
- The workaround is to use the `gcloud auth print-identity-token` command and to pass the result to your app and use it in your code -> But you loose consistency between code execution in local with your user account (and the gcloud command trick), and code execution on GCP (or elsewhere) with a service account.

Hope this help to know how to move ahead.

Comment: Maybe I read your answer incorrectly, but you can generate Identity Tokens from user account credentials (Google Accounts, G Suite, etc). A service account is not required to generate an Identity Token.

Comment: @JohnHanley. you are correct. You can generate an identity Token, **BUT** it's not accepted by Google Front End (self signed aren't accepted)

Comment: Identity Tokens generated from Google user accounts are not self-signed. They are signed by Google. When you authenticate with OAuth, you can optionally receive three tokens (Access Token, Identity Token, and Refresh Token).

Comment: @JohnHanley, I never succeeded to generate a valid identity token with my Google user credential (with Application Default Credential). Even the libraries, when they detect a user credential doesn't allow to generate an identity token (By inheritance in Java and Python, the method is not available). I know you are a security guru, and if you have a sample (of magic) code to achieve this, I will send you a box of french wine!! :) :) :)

Comment: I am not speaking about using the CLI, I am speaking of the Google OAuth 2.0 Flow. I have examples of how to generate Identity Tokens on my website plus I emailed you a while back an example IIRC for node.js.

Comment: Here is a link to generating an identity token using curl: https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/

Comment: Sure, but I have an issue: I don't know the client_ID and the client secret of Google oauth IdP! I can have my own server, or even register my own website and have an identity token for it. But I can't generate a valid identity token which will be accepted by Google Front End!

Comment: Self signed aren't accepted, however we do have a /signJwt endpoint that actually gets you a Google-signed JWT using your credentials (key file or access token).

Comment: What is this /signJwt endpoint? I never heard about it. How to use it?

Comment: If you search `signjwt google` you can find it. I recommend refraining from adding answers if you’re not sure. :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. In any case, I'm sure that I never succeeded to call a private Cloud Function and Cloud Run without a service account (and without implementing impersonification in my code). I'm also sure that the client libraries that I use avoid to generate identity token based on User credential. Anyway, I will test this to see if, at the end, it finally works. But, again, I'm not fan to customize my code to run it locally, and run without this hack in production. The best place is in the Google auth libraries!